# Is there a way to substitute a string name for a key “value” in buckets of aggregation results

Tags: elasticsearch

Here is the aggregation:

```
 "aggs" : {
 "bucketA" : {
 "terms" : { "field" : "field1" }
 }
```

Here is the results:

```
 "bucketA": {
 "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
 "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
 "buckets": [
 {
 "key": "value1",
 "doc_count": 667
 },
 {
 "key": "value2",
 "doc_count": 328
 },
 {
 "key": "value3",
 "doc_count": 1
 }
 ]
 }
```

I want to have a file (I imagine store in Elasticsearch somewhere?) that contains the replacement values:

```
"value1" : "replacement1"
"value2" : "replacement2"
"value3" : "replacement3"
```

Is there a way to specify this in the "aggregation", or do I have to capture the result and do the substitution subsequently?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply this substitution only for aggregation, then no, you should do it on the client side. If it's ok to substitute the terms when you index your documents, then you can use `synonyms` token filter, but it will affect the search results. See details here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/using-synonyms.html

Comment: No, I can't substitute at index time.  It seems like there may be a way to do this using a script - assuming that I can make a HTTP call from the script to do the search in the appropriate index given the value in the "key" from the aggregation.  I see that the getText() methods that Groovy adds to the java.net.URL class might allow me to create a URL that does the appropriate search.  Would this seem correct?  Is there an equivalent in the painless scripting?

Comment: You can try to substitute your values at query time using script but it would be much slower. So, if you need a proper performance, change your mapping.